# Starting a lengthy operation in a different thread freezes execution in the current one

Tags: java, multithreading

Either I don't actually understand multithreading, or something weird is happening.

I have the following piece of code:

```
public void playMusic(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            tune.play();
        }
    }).run();
    System.out.println("*******");
}
```

This method plays a piece of music. It starts a new thread and does the music-playing in there, to not pause the execution of the current thread.

As such I would expect `System.out.println("*********");` to be executed almost immediately when the method is called, since the lengthy operation `tune.play()` is invoked on a different thread.

However in practice `*********` is printed to the screen only when the music ends.

How do you explain this? And how can I separate the music-playing from the current thread?

If it makes a difference, the 'current thread' is the Swing EDT.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you start a new thread.

It should be :

```
public void playMusic(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            tune.play();
        }
    }).start();
    System.out.println("*******");
}
```

Calling the `run` method of the `Thread` you created will execute it on the current thread.

Comment: Ohhhhhh... funny stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't start the thread, you merely called `run` on it, so it's executed in your current thread.  [Call `start` to start the thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) instead.  Change

```
}).run();
```

to

```
}).start();
```